# Are “fuchzehn” and “fuchzig” dialectal expressions?

Tags: dialect, numbers

I noticed that people sometimes use *fuchzehn* and *fuchzig* instead of *fünfzehn* and *fünfzig.* Is there a certain reason or is this just dialect?

Comment: Can you tell us where people are doing this, so we have a better chance to identify a possible dialect?

Comment: IMHO [fuchzehn](http://www.dict.cc/?s=fuchzehn) and [fuchzig](http://www.dict.cc/?s=fuchzig) should not be in this dictionary.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft in austria

Comment: I have never heard that. We sometimes use "fuffzehn" and "fuffzig" in common speech (and "Nullachtfuffzehn").

Comment: @FranzEbner Why not? It is denoted as dialect.

Comment: @Carlster What would happen, if everyone would add his own dialect words? This would end in a total mess, unusable.

Comment: It's not unusable as long as it is clear what's dialect and what's not.

Comment: It says "English-German" not "Standard English-Standard German".

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Both words are used in articles on http://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoamseitn . So I guess it is Bavarian (bairisch/boarisch).

Comment: These words are used in several Austrian and Bavarian dialects. I can definitely confirm they are used here (Niederösterreich/Wien).

Comment: These words are also used in Karinthia (Austria) there they speak a dialect of the Bavarian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just dialect. Only "fünfzehn" and "fünfzig" are correct.

Answer (score 7):

The pronunciation *fuchzehn* (as well as *fuffzehn*) is a regional variant of the standard German word *fünfzehn.* It is mainly used in the south-east of the German language area. The area of distribution is shown in a linguistic map of the linguistic atlas [*Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f16/):

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]

Answer (score -1):

Ich kenne nur fuffzig und fuffzehn (Dialekt), nicht "fuchzig" oder "fuchzehn".

Comment: In Dialekten gibt es bekanntlich keine standardisierte Schreibweise oder Aussprache. Ich kenne jedenfalls beide Varianten.

Comment: "fuchzehn" und "fuchzig" kommen in österreichischen Dialekten vor.

Comment: Im bairischen auch.

Comment: Ich höre es oft in Erlangen.