# Mundart: fuffzehn und fuffzig (15 und 50). Warum nicht "fuff" für 5?

Tags: dialect, numbers

In Mundart (zumindest in Österreich) wird oft "fuffzehn" anstatt "fünzehn" gesagt. 
Ebenso wird "fuffzig" für "fünfzig" verwendet. Beide Wörter finden sich auch im Duden. ([fuffzehn](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuffzehn), [fuffzig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuffzig))

In diesen Fällen wird "fuff" für "fünf" verwendet. Das ist (soweit mir bekannt) aber nur bei diesen beiden Wörtern so. Niemand sagt z.B. "fuff" oder "fuffhundert".

Warum wird der Dialekt nur auf bestimmte Wörter angewandt und nicht auf alle?
Liegt es daran, dass bei beiden Beispielen nach fünf/fuff ein "z", also ein Zischlaut kommt?

Comment: Related: [Are “fuchzehn” and “fuchzig” dialectal expressions?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15195/are-fuchzehn-and-fuchzig-dialectal-expressions)

Comment: In Berlin sagt man das auch ständig so.

Comment: "Fünfzehn" und "fünf" verlangen dem Sprecher vier konsonantische Artikulationen in Folge ab (Nasal n, Frikativ f, Plosiv und dann Frikativ für z). Daher ist die Tendenz zur Vereinfachung größer als in "fünf", wo nur zwei aufeinanderfolgen.

Comment: Danke @Kilian. Also lag ich mit meiner Vermutung, dass es am darauffolgenden "z" liegt, richtig.

Comment: IANAL, aber der Vorgang, der zu *zwanzig* und dem kurzen *i* in *vierzig* geführt hat, könnte ähnlich sein.

Comment: In einigen schwäbischen Mundarten heißt die "fünf" dann auch "feif". "Feifzig" und "Feifhundert" folgen konsequent.

Answer (score 2):

Es handelt sich um eine Reduktion (hier noch im Dialekt), die das schnelle Sprechen erleichtert. Die Laute für "...uffz..." liegen sprechtechnisch näher zusammen als "...ünfz..." und können so leichter formuliert werden. Das "u" spricht sich zudem noch einfacher als das "ü", da es näher am Murmellaut liegt.

Analog verhält es sich z.B. bei "hammer" für "haben wir" oder "einmannfrei" für "einwandfrei".